# EXC_BREAKPOINT on optional chaining

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm new to Swift but I'm an experienced iOS dev on Objective-c.
Currently, crashlytics have reported a EXC_BREAKPOINT crash to a single user, but it's systematic.
I've tried with multiple devices and OSes version but I cannot reproduce It.

line is:

```
if(RealmManager.sharedInstance()?.loggedUser()?.agreementPhotoRead.boolValue ?? false || PreferencesManager.getTutorialDone(forEmail: RealmManager.sharedInstance()?.loggedUser()?.email)){
    }
```

What's wrong with optional chaining? Swift version is 4.2.

EDIT:
`geTutorialDone` method is in objective-c. Here the code:

```
+ (BOOL)getTutorialDoneForEmail:(NSString *)email
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[TUTORIAL_PREF stringByAppendingString:email]];
}
```

Comment: Does the method: `PreferencesManager.getTutorialDone(forEmail:)` can handle an optional value which can be nil as well?

Comment: @LoVo added the body of the method

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `stringByAppendingString` method doesn't actually work in case its input argument `NSString` is `nil` as explained in the [documentation of the method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412307-stringbyappendingstring?language=objc).

> Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aString is nil.

You should do a `nil` check before calling the method in `getTutorialDoneForEmail` or even better, make `getTutorialDoneForEmail` accept only non-`nil` `NSString`s.

```
+ (BOOL)getTutorialDoneForEmail:(nonnull NSString *)email {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[TUTORIAL_PREF stringByAppendingString:email]];
}
```

Moreover, if `agreementPhotoRead` can be `nil`, you need to optional chain its call to `boolValue`, otherwise Swift will handle it as an implicitly unwrapped optional, which will result in a runtime error in case `agreementPhotoRead` was actually `nil`.

```
RealmManager.sharedInstance()?.loggedUser()?.agreementPhotoRead?.boolValue
```

Comment: and Why Crashlytics report a `EXC_BREAKPOINT` on `continueToRecording` and not a `NSInvalidArgumentException` on `getTutorialDone` ? I'm also sure that the user that have the issue is passing an email and not a `nil` value.

Comment: @AlessioCrestani you could easily test this by modifying your call to `getTutorialDone(forEmail:)` to get passed a `nil` value on purpose like `if(RealmManager.sharedInstance()?.loggedUser()?.agreementPhotoRead.boolValue ?? false || PreferencesManager.getTutorialDone(forEmail: nil)){
    }` Btw there's no mention of a `continueToRecording` method in your question...

Comment: `continueToRecording()` is the method that have the `if` statement as its first line, sorry if I've not metioned It before.

Comment: @AlessioCrestani another possible point of error might be not optional chaining `agreementPhotoRead.boolValue`, but I cannot tell for sure without more context.

Comment: I've tried to pass a nil email to `getTutorialDone` and as I've previously said, the error is `NSInvalidArgument` and not the `EXC_BREAKPOINT`. What context do you need for the optional chaining problems? I can write all the methods

Comment: Many errors are only displayed as as EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION or EXC_BREAKPOINT when a swift expectation is incorrect and only trigger a runtimetrap and the apps entry point is not written in swift.  Some of them are:  - forced unwrapping nil,
-forced-try expressions (try!) producing an error,
- out-of-bounds indexing into arrays,
- precondition failures,
- assertion failures,
- fatalError calls

Comment: @AlessioCrestani what's the type of `agreementPhotoRead`? Can it actually be `nil`? Is it an implicitly unwrapped Optional in Swift?

Comment: '@property NSNumber<RLMBool> *agreementPhotoRead;' is the property in Objective-C. Of course, It can be 'nil'

Comment: @AlessioCrestani in that case you should be optional chaining the call to `boolValue` as well :) `RealmManager.sharedInstance()?.loggedUser()?.agreementPhotoRead?.boolValue`